# Block Websites via Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, block

How can I programmatically block sites through the Chrome browser?

My idea is to do it through a custom extension, so I think it would be implemented in JavaScript.

I think it's as simple as redirecting from the page the user enters to a custom error page -- but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this (I haven't really done Chrome extensions before)

Comment: What would be to stop the user disabling the extension and hence, the filter?

Comment: Actually, the only user will be me...I'm just doing as an excercise, but also to help my productivity (I spend wayyyy too much time on this site) =). So, nothing, just my willpower.

Comment: But I also saw one a while back where you had to type in 64 characters of text from an image before you could override, which is an interesting concept.

Comment: :D - That's an interesting idea - validate input or 'no navigate'. I'd probably just download an extension that already does this, then look at it's source (it's just a .zip file, with the extension changed to .crx) Here's an extension that already blocks sites: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en - I've also seen an extension that will let you quickly view the source of other (installed) extensions too, without locating and opening the .crx file. I forget its name (i'm on another pc just now)

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks! I'll check it out...it seems like a lot of file types are really just renamed zips...I know EPUBs are, and PAGESs are too =)

Comment: No worries mate. Android applications too (renamed zip files). I found the name of that other extension I mentioned: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin You don't actually have to install (other) extensions to be able to read their source. Quite a handy tool. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and its samples.

They will achieve exactly what you need: you detect an attempt to open a page in `onBeforeRequest` in your background script, analyze the request and optionally redirect it to your page implementing your logic.

See CatBlock sample [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#webrequest) for a starting point.